# Disabling all controls during a callback

Tags: c#, callback, devexpress

I have a DevExpress Callback panel with a group of buttons and a text box inside of it. When the user clicks a button, it adds the message to the textbox and performs a callback. Users can also type into the text box, and when the textbox loses focus, it also performs a callback. When the callback is occurring, a modal loading panel appears to stop users from spamming buttons to fast and jumbling the words up in the text box (I'm sure I could handle this better with my jQuery code, but I am pretty new to that, so I am doing the best I can). My main issue is that while a callback is being performed, the User can keep typing the text box, and the new text gets deleted when the callback finishes. My conclusion is that I just wanted to stop all input during the callback, so I was hoping there would be a way to disable all the controls inside of the panel during the callback, and then re-enable them when its done. I know it is possible to hide them, but that is quite the eyesore IMHO.

any ideas?